# How to change fragment from component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to change fragment of the url programatically from the component but I'm failing to do so.

```
<a #linkComponent routerLink='home' fragment='part'>link</a>

@ViewChild('linkComponent') linkComponent;

this.linkComponent.????
```

Or maybe there is a different way maybe using [Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modifying linkComponent will only change the element and I was after changing fragment URL. Here's an example in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#fragment). Below I have a working solution.

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class Cmp {
  constructor( private router: Router ) { }

  changeFragment() {
    this.router.navigate( [ '/home' ], { fragment: 'part' } )
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is a couple years old so it might work differently now in Angular 5 than previous versions - but you don't include the `#` when setting the fragment this way anymore. Otherwise this works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You probably need something like this:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class Cmp {

    @ViewChild('linkComponent') linkComponent: ElementRef;

    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer) {}

    // only after view initialization linkComponent would be available!
    ngAfterViewInit() {

        this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this.linkComponent, 'fragment', 'new_value');
    }

}
```